# Flutter integration test - Check icon type has changed when pressing list row

Tags: testing, flutter, dart, integration-testing

I'm trying out flutter and I've basically followed along with the getting started Codelabs

- https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab
- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#0

But I'm attempting to add some integration tests to it. Basically what I want is to check if the icon is `Icons.favourite` when the list row is pressed. All other examples I've come across see only checks for text on a screen. Heres the test file:

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  group('My App', () {
    final firstListItem = find.byValueKey('list_title_0');

    FlutterDriver driver;

    setUpAll(() async {
      driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
    });

    tearDownAll(() async {
      if (driver != null) {
        driver.close();
      }
    });

    test('name is favourited', () async {
      await driver.tap(firstListItem);

      final SerializableFinder firstFavourite = find.byValueKey('favourite_0_saved');

      await driver.waitFor(firstFavourite);

      // not sure what to expect for here..
    });
  });
}
```

Below is the code for the app. It's Basically the codelabs code. The only change I've made is the addition of `key` to `Icon` so I can use it for the finder during testing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      home: RandomWords(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RandomWordsState createState() => RandomWordsState();
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final Set<WordPair> _saved = Set<WordPair>();
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Startup Name Generator'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: _pushSaved),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildSuggestions(),
    );
  }

  void _pushSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: 
        (BuildContext context) {
          final Iterable<ListTile> tiles = _saved.map((WordPair pair) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                pair.asPascalCase,
                style: _biggerFont,
              ),
            );
          });
          final List<Widget> divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
            context: context,
            tiles: tiles
          ).toList();

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Saved Suggestions'),
            ),
            body: ListView(children: divided),
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return Divider();

        final index = i ~/ 2;
        if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
        }
        return _buildRow(_suggestions[index], i);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair, int i) {
    final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);

    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        pair.asPascalCase,
        style: _biggerFont,
      ),
      key: Key('list_title_$i'),
      trailing: Icon(
        alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
        color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
        key: alreadySaved ? Key('favourite_${i}_saved') : Key('favourite_${i}_unsaved'),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (alreadySaved) {
            _saved.remove(pair);
          } else {
            _saved.add(pair);
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need integration tests for this – widget tests will do about as well while not needing an emulator.

Comment: @RémiRousselet, yeah I considered unit tests. Although I wanted to just play around with integration tests to mostly get a feel for them in flutter. Are integration tests limited to only text checking on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect(find.widgetWithIcon(Widget, Icons), findsOneWidget);` to look for the Widget with the expected Icon on Screen. Another approach that you can use is by assigning Keys on the Icon.

```dart
iconFavoriteActive() =>
  return Icon(Icons.favorite, key: Key('keyIconFavoriteActive'));
```

To test, use `find.byKey()`

```dart
expect(find.byKey(Key('keyIconFavoriteActive')), findsOneWidget);
```